# How to hide form by default and show on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a comment form which is showed by a php while loop like

```
Post 1
Comment box 1

Post 2
Comment box 2
```

i want to hide the comment box by default and when the user click on comment link then the form should be shown

here is what I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#showActionComment").hide();
    $("#showActionComment").click(function() {
        $("#comForm").show();
    });
});
```

Html

```
php while loop starts here
Post 1
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="comForm">Comment</a>
<form action="/comment.php" class="form-horizontal" id="showActionComment">
<input type="text" name="comment">
</form>

php while loop ends here
```

Due to loop there may be 15 post
above code doesn't work in my case

Comment: You should use CSS to hide element initially i.e. `.form-horizontal{display:none;}`

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#showActionComment', function() {
 $("#comForm").show();
});` for dynamically added form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating elements in a loop with same id. **Identifiers in HTML must be unique** otherwise it invalid HTML. You can use class selector and there relationship to traverse between elements

*CSS*
    .showActionComment{ display:none;}

*PHP Script to generate HTML*

```
php while loop starts here

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="comForm">Comment</a>
    <form action="/comment.php" class="form-horizontal showActionComment">
        <input type="text" name="comment">
    </form>

php while loop ends here
```

*jQuery Script*, You need to subscribe click event on `comForm` element not `form`. Here in the code snippet I have used [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(document).on('click',".comForm", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".showActionComment").show();
});
```

Note: use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Comment: @SagarSingh, Whats not working? Please be specific and elaborate so that we can help you

Comment: after clicking on comment nothing happens i checked the console also but no error and when i remove $(this).next and replace it with $(".showActionComment").show(); it worked but when i clicked on comment it showed me all the comment form

Comment: @SagarSingh, Please share the  exact HTML maybe in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) we are missing something

Answer (score 0):

Set the **display:none** property for the class.

```
.form-horizontal{
     display:none
}
```

Whenever you refresh the page, it will not display the form.
  On click event, it will change **display:none** to **display:block** as per your click event.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the form by default via css

```
#comForm {
display:none;
}
```

and then once the button is clicked show it

```
 $("#showActionComment").click(function() {
        $("#comForm").show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this - note IDs must be unique:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".showForm").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".showActionComment").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.showActionComment { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="enableJavaScript.html" class="showForm">Comment</a>
<form action="/comment.php" class="form-horizontal showActionComment">
<input type="text" name="comment">
</form><br/>
<a href="enableJavaScript.html" class="showForm">Comment</a>
<form action="/comment.php" class="form-horizontal showActionComment">
<input type="text" name="comment">
</form>
```

If you load the comments and links using AJAX, change

```
  $(".showForm").on("click",function(e) {
```

to

```
  $(document).on("click",".showForm",function(e) {
```

Comment: code is working totally fine but when i click on link it shows the form of first post as all id are same and it is in loop

Comment: Change the IDs to CLASS - it is ONLY showing the NEXT comment after the link in my code

Comment: first 15 post are fetched simply from database after 15 all post are fetched by ajax! code doesn't seem to work

Comment: Errors in console?